# How can I track how many and where my flutter app is making firestore queries?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a flutter/dart app connected to google firestore, and in the Google firestore usage panel, I'm seeing far more read queries made than I expect based on my code. I've put guards around where I think the queries are happening (i.e.:

```
static bool queried = false;
assert (!queried);
queried = true;
make query
```

And I'm still seeing something like 2000-3000 queries made by my app in just a few minutes of usage in the iOS emulator.

I can't seem to find any tool for profiling this or general tracing of where queries are made. I'm concerned they're being made under the covers of some other library I'm including.

Comment: There is no way to see where the reads come from in the console. But keep in mind that keeping the Firestore data viewer open in the Firebase or Cloud console will actually read the data. So quite often unexplained reads may come from there.

Comment: Well, I was more looking for a way to track it from the client side - some logging I could turn on in the Firebase/Firestore objects themselves to see when a query is made.

Comment: The Firestore Android SDK has an option to enable such logging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#setLoggingEnabled(boolean), but it seems like the FlutterFire library doesn't wrap that method: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore-class.html